# Unable to successfully receive JSON data to .NET MVC Controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm aiming to build up a JSON array of mouse positions and pass them to a controller.  For some reason my json is returning from the controller as undefined can anyone spot my problem?

```
// Attempt at declaring a JSON object
var personResults = { "answers": [] };

// Onclick I fire in values from mouse event
personResults.answers[count] = { "xpos": mouseX, "ypos": mouseY };

// AJAX Call
$.ajax({
    url: "Save",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(personResults),
    success: function (data) { alert(data.toSource()); },
    error: function (req, status, error) {
        alert("error! " + status +    error + req);
    }
});
```

I then receive the jsontext from my .NET MVC Controller:

```
public JsonResult Save(string personResults)
{
    return Json(personResults);
}
```

As you can see the response back to the AJAX should just be the same json I sent to it - but I'm receiving undefined values back from the server even though my json seems to be constructing Ok and I've tested it - it's valid.

If I set Save to receive of type "string" I receive this alert "(new String(""))";  if i set the save action to receive of type "JsonResult" I receive this alert:

```
({ContentEncoding:null, ContentType:null, Data:null, JsonRequestBehavior:1})
```

Am I missing something totally obvious?  I just want to check that my json is being sent successfully to the controller so I can manipulate it later!

Here's the format of my JSON:

```
{"answers":[
    {"xpos":293,"ypos":415},{"xpos":293,"ypos":415},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416},
    {"xpos":293,"ypos":416},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416},
    {"xpos":293,"ypos":416},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416},
    {"xpos":293,"ypos":416},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416},
    {"xpos":293,"ypos":416},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416},
    {"xpos":293,"ypos":416},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416},
    {"xpos":293,"ypos":416},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416},
    {"xpos":293,"ypos":416},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416},
    {"xpos":293,"ypos":416},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416},
    {"xpos":293,"ypos":416},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416},
    {"xpos":293,"ypos":416},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416},
    {"xpos":293,"ypos":416},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416},
    {"xpos":293,"ypos":416},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416},
    {"xpos":293,"ypos":416},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416},{"xpos":293,"ypos":416}
]}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I understand your question you want to know **how to send data (input parameters) to the action of your MVC controller** which will return `JsonResult` back.

Your first error is that input data of the action `Save` should be **not in JSON format**. MVC in designed more to work with forms, so if you send any data to the `Save` action the data must be **url-encoded**. For example to have "Bla Bla" as input of `personResults` parameter of the action `Save` your jQuery call should be following

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Home/Save",
    type: "POST",
    data: "personResults=Bla+Bla",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data); },
    error: function (req, status, error) {
        alert("error! " + status + error );
    }
});
```

More better not make any manual encoding of the string "Bla Bla" and use `data: {personResults: "Bla Bla"}` instead of `data: "personResults=Bla+Bla"`.

If you want to send more complex data to the MVC controller you can do this but you have to convert the data to JSON and back manually. For example if you include a new action `Save1`:

```
public JsonResult Save1 (string encodedAnswers) {
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    MyData data = serializer.Deserialize<MyData> (encodedAnswers);
    return Json (data);
}
```

where `MyData` defined as

```
public class MyData
{
    public List<MyPosition> answers { get; set; }
}
public class MyPosition
{
    public int xpos { get; set; }
    public int ypos { get; set; }
}
```

(In the same way you can use [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) instead of [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx).)
The corresponding JavaScript code could be following

```
var personResults = {"answers":[{"xpos":293, "ypos":415 },{"xpos":293, "ypos":416}]};
// or var personResults = {answers: [{xpos: 293, ypos: 415},{xpos: 293, ypos: 416}]};

$.ajax({
    url: "Home/Save1",
    type: "POST",
    data: {encodedAnswers: JSON.stringify(personResults)},
    success: function (data) {
        alert("answers[0].xpos="+data.answers[0].xpos); },
    error: function (req, status, error) {
        alert("error! " + status +    error );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your indepth response this is more than I could have hoped for!  I was basically trying to see if my Json was valid as I need to map it to a dataclass like you have shown above.  So now I'm deserializing the string to a class object and looping through that object to perform operations on the values! cheers =]

Comment: Thanks to all the responses as well your time was appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I really don't understand the usefulness of your controller action but if you simply want it to return the same JSON string as it received as input you could use the `Content` method:

```
public ActionResult Save(string personResults)
{
    return Content(personResults, "application/json");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your $.Ajax call is turning the data into a string, and the you are returning just a string.  It may nont be ableto figure out how to process this, and it may not be necessary.

However, suggest you try this in your controller:

```
return Json( new { personResults = personResults } );
```