# Receive JSON in MVC controller

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my first time using JSON and I'm having a bit of trouble parsing and using it in my controller. I already tried these solutions [Unable to successfully receive JSON data to .NET MVC Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840434/unable-to-successfully-receive-json-data-to-net-mvc-controller), [How to receive JSON as an MVC 5 action method parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578814/how-to-receive-json-as-an-mvc-5-action-method-parameter), but none of them made it for me.

I'm retrieving some data from my html and sending the arrays through ajax to the controller in the following code:

JQuery:

```
var values = $('ul#values li').map(function() {
   return this.textContent;
}).get()

var lines = $('ul#lines li').map(function() {
    return {
       Column: this.textContent,
       Table: this.getAttribute("name")
    };
}).get();

var columns = $('ul#lines li').map(function() {
    return {
       Column: this.textContent,
       Table: this.getAttribute("name")
    };
}).get();

var filters = $('ul#filters li.panel').map(function () {

            var n = this.getAttribute("name");

            var c = $(this).children()[1].textContent;

            var r = $(this).find("li input:checked").map(function() {
                return this.parentNode.textContent;
            }).get();
            if (r.length === 0)
                return null;
            else
                return { table: n, name:c, vals: r };
        }).get();


 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/PivotTable",
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        data: {
            indicators: values,
            lines: JSON.stringify(lines) ,
            columns:  JSON.stringify(columns),
            filters:  JSON.stringify(filters)
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.s, data.l);
        }

    });
```

And this is the form data being posted:

```
indicators:  Taxa Mensal de inflação
lines:[{"Column":"  Base","Table":"D_Base"}]
columns:[{"col":"  Trimestre","table":"D_Calendario"}]
filters:[{"table":"D_PF_ClasseProdutos","name":"  Código","vals":[" 22"," 23"]}]
```

And receiving the data in the controller where I need to access the data:

```
public JsonResult PivotTable(string[] indicators, Lines[]  lines, object[] columns, object[] filters)
        {
            string sa = indicators[0];

            var l = lines;
            var col = columns;
            var fil = filters;

            var result = new { s = sa, l=l[0].Column};
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

public class Lines
        {
            public string Column { get; set; }
            public string Table { get; set; }
        }
```

I tried binding lines to an object, like the solution in one of the links,  but got

> NullRefrenceException was unhandled by usercode

While the other parameters receive the appropriate 
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dp2Zp.png), but i can´t access the properties of the object.

What am I doing wrong, and how can i parse the data or bind it to an object?

Comment: Please show us the code for the `Lines` class. Also, you can't use `object[] columns` like that (same for filters). You need to have `YourConcreteClass[] columns` instead.

Comment: Remove the `JSON.stringify()` calls. You're effectively double-wrapping the JSON in those properties as jQuery will serialise the entire object before sending

Comment: The code for Lines class is bellow the controller, but using a class gave me the NullReference error.  In the meantime I will try what you sugested

Comment: Removing the `JSON.stringify()`  made the data an object instead of JSON

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try to use Json.NET library which allows you to serialize and deserialize.

Pass your params as string and do the following:

```
Lines[] m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Lines>(lines);
```

Comment: Your solution solve my problem. I had to change `Lines[ ] m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Lines[ ]>(lines);` Thanks!